# AppWidgetProvider onEnabled() -- is widget list known at that point?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I use `AlarmManager` to set a repeating alarm for each widget for updating purposes.  It's working well, on most devices.

In order to re-establish the alarms after a reboot, I am relying on the [`onEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled(android.content.Context)) method, since that is called once for the group of app widgets.  And in that, I have something like the following:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
int appWidgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class));
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
    // call function to set the repeating alarm for this widget (including doing a widget update NOW)...
    updateAppWidgetAlarm(context, appWidgetId, appWidgetManager, alarmManager);
}
```

Whilst this seems to work well in most cases, it appears that for some devices the `onEnabled()` method is not doing anything at all.  I know that it is being called, from some logging I put in, but nothing is happening.

I suspect that maybe the `appWidgetIds` array is empty, because at this early time after a reboot the list has not yet been populated.  I will put in some more logging to see if that is correct.

Am I using `onEnabled()` for something it was not intended?  Should the `appWidgetIds` array always have meaningful content at this point in the app widgets' lifecycle?

I have also tried delaying the above stuff for a short time by wrapping it inside a `handler.postDelayed()`, with uncertain results.